# Debugging WPF window is in the way blocking the editor

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Whenever I debug a WPF program or any windows program in Visual Studio at the initialization code, using step into feature, the wpf window always goes on top of the editor and I cant see whats behind it, this is of course during the process of initializing the main app which becomes unresponsive thus not able to move the idling window out of the way so I can see what I am debugging.

Is there a way around this? This might be a silly question if there is an obvious solution I apologize in advanced. Hopefully the question make sense.

**Update:** Here is the screen shot of what I'm dealing with. 
As you can see in here "Ernanis Renamer" window blocks the view, and if I try to drag it and move it away, It wont let me as it is suspended and need to continue until all component is displayed.
[image]

```html
**Update:** Here is a video of a simple annoyance that I keep getting every time I try to debug during initialization.
<div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RmbMGqcMtiU?ecver=2" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Normally, the debugger will remain in front. Why is your situation different? How is it that during initialization, your window is even visible (since it hasn't been initialized yet), never mind is blocking the debugger window? Setting TopMost to true will cause this to happen, but only after the window is visible (and the fix is obvious: don't set TopMost). You'll need to be more specific, making sure to include enough detail and preferably a good [mcve] showing exactly how you got into this situation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Here I added a screen shot of what I am dealing with. I may have come to a realization that maybe what I am trying to step into is in the middle of the initialization of the window thus showing an incomplete window.

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot doesn't improve your question. Your description of the symptom was clear enough. It's understanding the _cause_ that's the problem, and there's not a single piece of information in your question that would help us understand that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Oh I understand. I was under the impression that this could be fix by a simple option in the editor. I will add more info about the cause as a beginner  the resulting app would have been moveable via just dragging the window. I will try to add a video if I can to easily describe how I got into the symptom.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you've set the `TopMost` property for the window. There is still the question of why your window is already visible, if you really are still initializing it. Again, the details you need to provide are those that explain why your program is behaving like this in the first place. Adding a video to your question isn't useful. Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The "topmost" behaviour might be being added in a non-obvious manner (e.g. a window style, or some quirky codebehind), which is why you can't find it.

To definitively answer the question as to whether your "Window" is being made to be "Always On Top" / "TopMost", download Windows Detective.

- http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/

Install it, and run it with "Administration Rights".

"Pick"/"Find" your application window (make sure it is the outermost/main frame window) while it is running, and then choose "Edit Properties" (as it shows the flag clearer).

[image]

You then have various ways to "handle" the situation your errant window.

- 1) Use Window Detective to turn ON the Always on Top for Visual Studio - so it can come before your app window
- 2) Use Window Detective to turn OFF the Always on Top for your app window
- 3) Put some code into your app (after the window intialization but before where you are debugging/tracing) so it turns OFF topmost IF you are attached/running it from a debugger e.g.

  ```
  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
  {
      this.Topmost = false;
  }
  ```

You then won't forget to "keep" the "topmost" behaviour if that is "part" of your design.